# Android Studio - Http Post - Json - respond error bad request

Tags: java, android, json, http-post

My source code:

```
    final Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();


            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://pc.dyndns-office.com/mobile.asp");

                obj.put("Model", ReadIn1);
                obj.put("Product", ReadIn2);
                obj.put("Manufacturer", ReadIn3);
                obj.put("RELEASE", ReadIn4);
                obj.put("SERIAL", ReadIn5);
                obj.put("ID", ReadIn6);
                obj.put("ANDROID_ID", ReadIn7);
                obj.put("Language", ReadIn8);
                obj.put("BOARD", ReadIn9);
                obj.put("BOOTLOADER", ReadIn10);
                obj.put("BRAND", ReadIn11);
                obj.put("CPU_API", ReadIn12);
                obj.put("DISPLAY", ReadIn13);
                obj.put("FINGERPRINT", ReadIn14);
                obj.put("HARDWARE", ReadIn15);
                obj.put("UUID", ReadIn16);

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                post.setHeader("host", "http://pc.dyndns-office.com/mobile.asp");

                response = client.execute(post);

                if (response != null) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Looper.loop();
        }
    };

    t.start();
 }
}
```

i want to send an Json object to a Website. As far as I can see, I set the header, but still I get this exception, can someone help me?

(I'm using Android-Studio)
__

Edit: I don't get any exceptions anymore, but still I do not receive the json packet.

When I manually call the website I get a log file entry.

Does anyone know, what's wrong?

Edit2:
When I debug I get as response "HTTP/1.1 400 bad request" I'm sure it's not an permission problem. Any ideas?

Comment: 400 Bad request means you didn't send what the server expected. What does the server expect?

Comment: your host parameter is wrong, I think it should be pc.dyndns-office.com . Take a look [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23)

Comment: when my host parameter was pc.dyndns-office.com, than i became the exception that the host can't be null.

Comment: I'm facing something similar. Guessing by the age of this post, I don't think you'd still be stuck here. My code is similar and this issue arises when I'm sending headers using `setHeaders()`. Since the headers aren't mandatory yet, the request is always successful without headers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

replace `StringEntity(String)` by  `ByteArrayEntity(stringValue.getBytes("UTF8"));` and use it.

like :

```
 httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(params.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

where params is jsonObject of map contains input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```